# ransomware- why recreate file then delete instead of overwriting?

Tags: file, privileges, uac, overwrite, malware

I've been researching a lot of well known ransomware variants and it seems most of them copy, encrypt, write to a new file then delete the original.

Is there any advantage to this in comparison to simply overwriting the original file with the encrypted data? Wouldn't overwriting the original file make it harder to recover, thus making more effective?

If UAC got in the way, wouldn't the former just leave the original file and create a separate encrypted-version of the file alongside it, while the latter just wouldn't be able to edit the files?

Is there a difference and if so, why?